# How to get list of azsphere device wifi show-status?

Tags: azure-iot-hub, azure-sphere

I am getting for single device for below command

azsphere device wifi show-status

SSID : xxxxxxx

Configuration state : enabled

Connection state : connected

Security state : psk

Frequency : 2xxx

Mode : station

Key management : WPA2-PSK

WPA State : COMPLETED

IP Address : 195.xxxxxxx

MAC Address : 26:xxxxxxxxx

Command completed successfully in 00:00:0xxxxxxx.

How to get for list of multiple device mac ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The command `azsphere device wifi show-status` is meant to show the status of the Wi-Fi interface on the attached device.

Even if there are multiple devices connected to the Windows machine, the command line enforces you to specify the device ID, IP address or the Local Connection ID of the attached device. Please refer the below image for more details on the parameters of the command.

[image]

Here is the link to the official documentation on [Azure Sphere CLI command interface](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure-sphere/reference/azsphere-device?tabs=cliv2beta#wifi-show-status).

Even if you have multiple connected devices, the only way to achieve what you are looking for, with the current implementation, is to run the command against each connected device individually.

Comment: Thank you for your response LeelaRajesh_Sayana. We could make it work using the connection path for multiple devices. But we faced issues when using device id? What could be the reason for it? Thank you.